# How to run Angular Change Detection outside the app?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write Chrome extension which allows me to login to Angular Application. Application is built in prod mode.
I fill up `username` and `password` input fields programmatically

```
document.getElementById('username').value = 'User Name';
document.getElementById('password').value = 'pass';
document.getElementById('submit').click();
```

But `Submit` button is inactive because validation isn't passed but validation isn't passed because Change Detection wasn't run too.

My question is how to run Change Detection of Angular App outside App?

Comment: Why do not you use reactive forms instead?? Check the tutorial here. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
About change detection you can user the ChangeDetectorRef class. More info here.
https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: I don't have access to Angular code at all. I can manipulate it from chrome extension.

Comment: Instead of (or on top of) just setting the values, try dispatching an `input` event on the inputs.

Comment: @mbojko could you provide an example?

Comment: Generally, I thought of something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript